# How to send a dict to AWS step functions as input\parameter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions

I am trying to activate a step fucntion with some input parameter

from the [aws documntation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.stop_execution) when calling `start_execution`
one should give input in the following way `"input": "{\"first_name\" : \"test\"}"`

I am trying now to send a dict and not a string but I always get an error I am running the following code:

```
nested_dict = {
              "key3_1": "value3_1",
              "key3_2": "value3_1",
              "key3_3": "value3_1"
        }
my_input_work = {"input":
                     "{\"key1\": \"value1\", "
                     "\"key2\": \"value2\"}",
                 #how to add  nested_dict here?
                 }

my_input_fail = {
    "input":
        {
          "key1": "value1",
          "key2": "value2",
          "key_3": {
              "key3_1": "value3_1",
              "key3_2": "value3_1",
              "key3_3": "value3_1"
        }
    }
}

response = step_functions.start_execution(
                stateMachineArn=my_state_machine_arn,
                input=json.dumps(my_input)
)
```

How can i add `nested dict` to `my_input_work`? or how should i create the input generally from python ?
super thx for the help!

Comment: You have to assign the nested dictionary to a new key or directly add the keys on that dictionary. You can select the input you need from the stepfunction easily.

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: @helpper can you share your error message/stacktrace?  Your code snippets look fine.